# Admin Sales Order shows 404 on multisite

Tags: multistore, ce-1.8.1.0

I cannot access order detail page under sales from back-end.

**I have three websites, each has one store view.**

I can see orders placed on the main store, but not the ones on the other stores (/en/ or /eu/) .
I am also getting

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Model_Store_Exception' in 
/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:1357
```

How can I fix this issue?

**UPDATE**

I recognized that once I put the store views /en/ or /eu/ under main website, then I can access the order detail page.
But as long as each store view is under each website, then I cannot access order details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was caused by one extension I have, which localize the address & name format.
Uninstalling this extension solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.If you are enabling compilation, Do one more time. otherwise, disable compilation. 

2. Remove /var/cache.

3. Reindex the database.
```

Comment: How can I index the database?

Comment: This is not helpful. This is a bug with multistore where you cannot view orders in admin as it tries to open them with a wrong store ID.

Comment: In your magento admin panel, 
System -> Index Management -> Check "Select All" and give Reindex.

Comment: I did reindex all, also deleted magento cache & browser cache. But still not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with multistore. Simple copy `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php` and amend the `getUrl()` function as follows:

```
/**
 * Generate url by route and parameters
 *
 * @param   string $route
 * @param   array $params
 * @return  string
 */
public function getUrl($route='', $params=array())
{
$params['_store'] = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(0);
/* end workaround */
    return Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl($route, $params);
}
```

Comment: I tried this now, but not working...